# Continue execution when all running process "console exe" are done

Tags: powershell

I am trying to continue the execution of my main Script once all "other .exe excexution" are done

Example :

```
$Nb = 3
for($i=1;$i -le $Nb;$i++){
Start-Process -FilePath "$DirectoryContainingEXE\Test$i\test$i.exe"
}
#Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
Write-Host "We are done"
```

I need to have the message "We are done" printed once test1.exe, test2.exe and test3.exe consoles disappear (I can not use Start-Sleep because I ignore how much it gonna take)

Notice : I am using PS2EXE

Help please !

Comment: have you tried `Get-Process` to see if the items are still running? i presume that you want to run these in parallel ... but just in case in sequence would be acceptable, have you tried the `-Wait` parameter of `Start-Process`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter `-PassThru` when you start the process with `Start-Process` so you will get the process id.
After that you can check each process id if still running.

```
#Start processes
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Processes = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i ++)
{
    $Processes += Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-Command Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; exit" -PassThru

}

#Wait for processes
[System.Int16]$FinishedProcesses = 0
while ($FinishedProcesses -ne $Processes.Count)
{
    $FinishedProcesses = 0
    foreach ($Process in $Processes)
    {
        if (-not (Get-Process -Id $Process.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
        {
            $FinishedProcesses ++
        }
    }
}

Write-Output -InputObject 'We are done'
```